# Call hook based on ModelClass. better solution then casting?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, casting, listener

I have a listener method in an abstract class:

```
public void AsyncTaskListener(AbstractModel result){
```

and a bunch of hooks:

```
protected void RecieveModelAHook(ConcreteModelA){}
protected void RecieveModelBHook(ConcreteModelB){}
protected void RecieveModelCHook(ConcreteModelC){}
```

Now when AsyncTaskListener is called, it should decide which hook to call.
At the moment i solved it like this:

```
public void AsyncTaskListener(AbstractModel result){}
    if(result instanceof ConcreteModelA){
         RecieveModelAHook((ConcreteModelA) result);
    }
    if(result instanceof ConcreteModelB){
         RecieveModelBHook((ConcreteModelB) result);
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution? Or maybe a pattern for such things?

The AsyncTask reads different JSON strings an creates models like ConcreteModelA, ConcreteModelB from it. Since every client should be able to handle different results i need the hooks.

In the AsyncTask i have a request types. 
request type 1 creates ConcreteModelA
request type 2 creates ConcreteModelB

It works for now, but i am not happy with the ugly casting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have use for the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Rather then having such a switch in your code that requires updating whenever you have a new case, try to make use of polymorphism by encapsulating the part that changes and moving it out of the class by usage of composition.